# Correct way to include jquery scripts in Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am using the following jquery script in a Wordpress site. It works fine when I do not enqueue jQuery. However, when jQuery is enqueued, it no longer runs.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
$(function() {

    var $sidebar   = $(".side"), 
        $window    = $(window),
        offset     = $sidebar.offset(),
        topPadding = 15;

    $window.scroll(function() {
        if ($window.scrollTop() >= 240) {
            $sidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
            });
        } else {
            $sidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: 0
            });
        }
    });

});
```

PS. Yes, I have tried changing the intial call from `$(function))` to `jquery(function))` but it still does not run.

Comment: Just for good measure (dont take this the wrong way) but did you try `jquery(function)` or `jQuery(function)` ? because it has to be the second one to work. And did you try to put it in a dom ready event?

Comment: @suicidal.banana  `$(function(){})` is dom ready wrapper. http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Oh shi- another thing learned :D thanks/my bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the `$` symbol to the function: `jQuery(function($){ })` so you can use it within your code. Otherwise you need to replace every `$` in your code with `jQuery`

See: [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)